# Ubuntu 14.10 init scripts: where to find shell function "clean_all"?

Tags: ubuntu, init.d

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 . One of the things that I prefer in my desktop is to not clear out /tmp . I'm trying to do the same in 14.10: to prevent the /tmp from being cleared at boot.

In one of the startup scripts ( `/etc/init.d/mountall-bootclean.sh` ), there's a call to "clean_all", which clears out /tmp. Now, for the life of me I can't find where it is defined:

```
 % sudo grep -r -w -l clean_all /etc
 /etc/init.d/mountall-bootclean.sh
 /etc/init.d/checkroot-bootclean.sh
 /etc/init.d/mountnfs-bootclean.sh
```

So lets look at one of those, `/etc/init.d/mountall-bootclean.sh` . It starts with:

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

. /lib/init/bootclean.sh
```

It's not defined in either of those. Out of frustration (and equipped with an SSD), I tried the following:

```
sudo find /bin /boot /etc /lib* /sbin /usr /var -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -s 4096 sudo grep -s -w -l clean_all
```

The result? It's only in the following files:

```
/etc/init.d/mountall-bootclean.sh
/etc/init.d/checkroot-bootclean.sh
/etc/init.d/mountnfs-bootclean.sh
/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimp.so
/var/log/auth.log
```

I must be missing something really obvious, for I can't seem to find `clean_all` defined anywhere! Any ideas?

PS: I checked, it's not a file either

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all about how do those scripts you are looking at work. After looking at them it seems to me that they cannot work at all because the clean_all function is missing; maybe it was supposed to exist in  /lib/init/bootclean.sh, but that file doesn't exist in my 14.10.

What you should be looking for is the [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) job to empty /tmp on every reboot:

```
 /etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf
```

which is called on boot:

```
# mounted-tmp - Clean /tmp directory
#
# Cleans up the /tmp directory when it does not exist as a temporary
# filesystem.

description     "Clean /tmp directory"

start on (mounted MOUNTPOINT=/tmp) or (mounted MOUNTPOINT=/usr)
# The "/tmp" here is just a default and is overridden by the "start on"
# case above. It protects someone from running this job directly and
# having no $MOUNTPOINT defined.
env MOUNTPOINT=/tmp

[...]
```